# How to link C Libraries to GCC

Tags: c, gcc

I run the following

```
./gcc -o test -ansi test.c -L/<other dirs>/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/include-fixed/
```

I get ...

```
test.c:3:18: error: no include path in which to search for stdio.h
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:7: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'
```

Here is the ls

```
jackie@jackie-Latitude-E6410:<Other dirs>/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.4.3/include-fixed/ ls
limits.h  linux  README  stdio.h  sys  syslimits.h
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For include files you probably want to use `-I` instead of `-L` which is what you use to specify locations the shared and static libraries themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `-L` to `-I` on the compile line

`-L` is for linking libraries and `-I` is for adding to the include search paths.

So you might get another error when it compiles and not link, then you will need to add a `-L` and a `-l` (unless you just add the needed libraries with full paths)